# AWS Glue - facing memory issue in join and storing it in S3

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have around 200 compressed JSON lines files each of 500MB stored in S3. Each JSON line has empid, empname and array column which holds raw resume text content. Each file  2500 JSON lines. I'm creating a dynamic frame,

```
f1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "s3",
    connection_options = {
        "paths": [ "<path>" ],
        "recurse": True,
        "groupFiles": "inPartition",
        "groupSize": "1048576",
        "compressionType":"gzip"
        },
        format="json"
)
```

I also have a compressed CSV lookup file stored in S3 which contains 2 columns (empid, empname) and 1M rows.Creating an dynamic frame,

```
f2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "s3",
    connection_options = {
        "paths": ["<filepath>"],
        },
        format="csv",
        format_options={
            'withHeader': True
        }
)
```

I'm doing an join with these two frames,

```
merged_frame = Join.apply(frame1 = f1, frame2 = f2, keys1 = ["empid", "empname"], keys2 = ["empid", "empname"])
```

Finally storing the matched result,

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = merged_frame,
    connection_type = "s3",
    connection_options = {
        "path": '<path>',
        "compression": "gzip"
    },
    format = "json",
)
```

Objective: Need to create a subset of records from huge dataset based on lookup file.

Im facing an out of memory issue and so moved from standard to G1 worker type with 6 workers and still facing the heap memory issue. Am i missing anything? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: when you say out of memory which memory you are talking about? Also you don't need to use groupFiles and groupSize option as your file is already big enough. Have you tried converting these dynamic frames to data frames using toDf and perform the join operation?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Driver` This is the error im getting.

Comment: Can you try s3listimplementation as mentioned here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-oom-java-heap-space-error/  and other methods mentioned from this doc ?

Comment: I have tried that but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update your complete script in the question ? Also have you tried converting dynamic frames to data frames tried joining them?